# Most efficient way of calling Mapbox Distance API for large list of coordinates

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I want to find all distances between many (~6000) places on a map. For this, I use [Mapbox's Distance API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-a-duration-matrix), which takes a list of max 100 coordinate pairs, and returns a matrix of distances between them.
So if you give it:

```
{
  "coordinates": [
    [13.41894, 52.50055],
    [14.10293, 52.50055],
    [13.50116, 53.10293]
  ]
}
```

It will return a matrix like this:

```
{
  "durations": [
    ["A to A", "A to B", "A to C"],
    ["B to A", "B to B", "B to C"],
    ["C to A", "C to B", "C to C"]
  ]
}
```

So, because I can't send a request with all 6000 places, I have to do it piecewise. After a few tries, I came up with this solution:

1. first get a set of all possible permutations of from/to pairs,
2. then get all permutations of a randomly-sampled subset with size 100 of above set,
3. subtract the smaller set from the bigger one, and plug the result into step 1
4. continue until the resulting set from step 3 is empty.

Here's working toy code in Python (without actual API calls, locations are represented by numbers):

```
import itertools
import random

def get_set(s, rsample_size):
    m_set = set([x[0] for x in s] + [x[1] for x in s])
    if len(m_set) < rsample_size:
        rsample_size = len(m_set)
    sampled = random.sample(set(m_set), rsample_size) #sampling
    return sampled, rsample_size

#all place features, but just numbers here
master = set(range(500))
#all possible permutations between them
master_combinations = set(itertools.permutations(master, 2))
print 'len of original combinations list', len(master_combinations)

c = 0
#API call limit
smpl_size = 100
while len(master_combinations) > 0:
    print 'start iter: ', c, '\t remaining combinations: ', len(master_combinations)
    #sampling 100 random locations
    combs, smpl_size = get_set(master_combinations, smpl_size)
    #a set of all possible permutations of above 100
    combs = set(itertools.permutations(combs, 2))
    #subtracting calculated pairs from all possible pairs
    master_combinations = master_combinations.difference(combs)
    c += 1
```

The above example finds distances between all possible pairs of 500 elements in 132 - 140 calls. I have two problems:

1. random sampling seems like very inexact way to determine the list of locations to send to the API, with many duplicated results, although it does converge in every case,
2. subtracting one big (a million tuples) from a really big (10 million tuples) set in Python causes a memory error on a Windows machine with 16GB RAM, although this is not a primary issue. I could probably partition original list into many smaller and apply a more convoluted approach.

My question, since I'm obviously brute-forcing my way though that list, is whether is there a more elegant and efficient approach to this?

I was thinking maybe:

- first construct a 6000 x 6000 numpy array with all place combinations, then subsampling it with a step of 60 and a range of offsets to produce initial distances,
- find out what is left, and only then use the wasteful aforementioned approach.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you all this effort? Can't you just write a nested loop for `6000 * 6000` calculations, just calculating distance between one pair at a time and just save it?

Comment: That would be 6 million API calls to an API with a limited rate (60 per minute). I'd take a little more than two months.

Comment: Oh...thats nice. So you going to implement my idea? (sorry...I didn't know rate limit) :P

Comment: Is there any way you could retrieve the coordinates of the locations instead and calculate the distances locally? Do you really need to compute every possible pairwise distance (there are much more efficient ways to find nearest neighbours etc.)?

Comment: Yes, I absolutely need to compute every possible pair of distances, and then I want to sum them by location.